# SQL Extract User Group Ids, which include ONLY the specified user ids

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have three tables, Users Table, UserGroup Table and Join Table of Users and UserGroups as user_groups_users.

```
user_group_ids | user_ids
    1             1
    1             2
    1             3
    2             1
    2             2
```

Now, I want only those user_group_ids, which has has contains only 1 and 2 user_ids. So, the for the above example, it should only output "2" user_group_id and not 1 because it also includes user_id 3.

So, What would the SQL query to get the correct output.
The best I could come up with is

```
SELECT user_group_id FROM user_groups_users WHERE user_id IN (1, 2) GROUP BY user_group_id HAVING Count(DISTINCT user_id) = 2;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT user_group_ids 
  FROM user_groups 
 GROUP 
    BY user_group_ids 
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN user_ids IN (1,2) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = COUNT(*);
```

or just

```
SELECT user_group_ids 
  FROM user_groups 
 GROUP 
    BY user_group_ids 
HAVING SUM(user_ids IN (1,2)) = COUNT(*);
```

(I've assumed that (user_ids,user_group_ids) are components of a PK. If not, then you may need to include your DISTINCT operator)

Comment: Thanks for your help. And, yes caught it correctly, that I would need to use DISTINCT since user_id and user_group_id belong to the join table user_groups_users and hence they have not been set to PK. But, when I am trying the DISTINCT operator before the user_ids, I am getting empty set.

Comment: That doesn't make sense. On the assumption that no `user_group_ids` can belong to the same `user_ids` more than once (and vice versa) then these columns are obvious candidates for a UNIQUE natural key, which may as well be PRIMARY.

Comment: There is no assumption, that user_group_ids cannot belong to the same user_ids. The User and UserGroup have many to many relationship. But, even when not using DISTINCT for user_ids, the above query solves my problem. Thumbs up !